# Estoy intentando correr un Bot de Telegram con ChatGpt, El error indica que "Updater.init()" ha recibido un argumento inesperado llamado 'token'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, telegram-bot, telegram.bot

El error que se muestra se debe a que estoy utilizando el argumento "token" al crear una instancia de la clase "Updater" en el código, pero la clase "Updater" no acepta ese argumento. El error específicamente indica que "Updater.init()" ha recibido un argumento inesperado llamado 'token'.

Quiero lanzar un bot con Inteliegencia Artifical, en este caso con ChatGpt y OpenAI. el bot lo voy a correr con Telegram.

Le agradezco de ante mano la yuda que me puedan brindar.

Aqui le dejo el codi:

```
import logging
import openai
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext
from telegram import Bot

API_KEY = "Api de TelegraM"

openai.api_key = "Api de Openai"

def handle_text(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
message = update.message.text
chat_id = update.message.chat_id
if message.lower().startswith("dibuja"):
    processing_message = context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Dibujando...")
    try:
        response = openai.Image.create(
            prompt=remove_first_word(message),
            n=1,
            size="1024x1024"
        )
        reply = response['data'][0]['url']
    except:
        reply = "Error llamando al servicio de Image"
        print(reply)
else:
    try:
        processing_message = context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Pensando...")
        reply = call_ChatGPT(message)
    except:
        reply = "Error llamando al servicio de ChatCompletion"
        print(reply)
    
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=reply)

def main():
updater = Updater(token=API_KEY, use_context=True)

dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.text, handle_text))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

El erro que me arroja es:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-1a11dcf158e3> in <cell line: 62>()
 61 
 62 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 63     main()

<ipython-input-15-1a11dcf158e3> in main()
 52 
 53 def main():
---> 54     updater = Updater(token=API_KEY, use_context=True)
 55 
 56     dp = updater.dispatcher

TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'
```

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que el inicializador de la clase [`telegram.ext.updater`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.6/telegram.ext.updater.html#updater) efectivamente no tiene un argumento `token` actualmente. Sus únicos argumentos son  `bot` y `update_queue`.

Tu código es valido para telegram-bot < v20.0, pero aparentemente estas usando una versión actual y la API cambio substancialmente en la versión 20, incluida la clase `Updater`.

Actualmente la clase que sirve de punto de entrada no es `Updater`, es [`Application`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.6/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application). `Updater` solo sirve para obtener las actualizaciones, siendo usada para ello por `Application`.

O bien usas una versión de telegram-bot anterior a la 20 o adaptas el código. Puedes mirarte [Transition guide to Version 20.0](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0) de la documentación oficial.

Nunca he usado telegram-bot antes, así que toma el código a continuación con precaución, pero debería ser algo así:

```
from telegram.ext import Application

# ....

def main():
    application = Application.builder().token(API_KEY).build()
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.text, handle_text))
    application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```