# Error Updater.__init__() got an unnexpected keyword argument 'use_context'

Tags: python, telegram, telegram.bot

Estoy intentando realizar un bot de Telegram para la reserva de pistas y encendido de luces.
Y al ejecutar el codigo con el bot me sale el error:

> `TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'`

Este es el código.

```
import datetime
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, CallbackContext

TELEGRAM_TOKEN = '----TOKEN ELIMINADO:-----'

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text('¡Hola! Soy un bot de reserva. ¿Cómo puedo ayudarte?')

def reservar(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Reservar ahora", callback_data='reservar')],
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text('¿Quieres reservar ahora?', reply_markup=reply_markup)

def button_reservar(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    query.edit_message_text(text="Reserva confirmada. ¡Gracias!")

def encender_luces(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text('Encendiendo luces...') # Aquí deberías agregar tu lógica para encender las luces

def main():
    updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_TOKEN, use_context=True)



    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("reservar", reservar))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button_reservar, pattern='reservar'))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("encender_luces", encender_luces))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

y este es el error:

```
File "k:\-----\----\Pistes esportives\platilla_reserva_v1.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "k:\-----\----\Pistes esportives\platilla_reserva_v1.py", line 33, in main
    updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_TOKEN, use_context=False)

              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'
```

Quito el `use_context=True` y me vuelve a salir error.

Comment: Hola Jordi, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Que versión de telegram-bot estas usando? sospecho que >=20, si es así mirate: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/606219/15089, ese codigo es para versiones anteriores a la 20 (y mayores a la 12). Por otro lado, ¿ alguna razon para la etiqueta python-2.7?, está en  EOL desde hace tiempo y tu código es para Python 3...

Comment: Hola, FJSevilla, lo de la etiqueta ha sido un error de guardado queria poner 3.
Por otro lado la versión es la última que hay. Muchas gracias